# Qt exit when hiding window

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `MainWindow` which calls the LoginWindow in the constructor. The `LoginDialog` has a button to create an account which will create a `QDialog`.

I wanted to hide the `LoginDialog` while the Dialog for the new account is showing but somehow it crashes.

When I remove the first and last line of the function which hides and shows the `LoginDialog` it's absolutely fine. Why does it crash with `hide()` and `show()` are called ?

```
void LoginDialog::createAccount()
{
    // (-> will cause crash later) hide(); //Hides LoginDialog
    QDialog dlg;
    dlg.setGeometry( this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height() );

    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget( &dlg );
    QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout( centralWidget );
    dlg.setLayout( l );

    QLineEdit *dlgUser = new QLineEdit( centralWidget );
    QLineEdit *dlgPass = new QLineEdit( centralWidget );
    dlgPass->setEchoMode( QLineEdit::Password );

    l->addWidget( new QLabel( tr("Username :"), centralWidget ) );
    l->addWidget( dlgUser );
    l->addWidget( new QLabel( tr("Password :"), centralWidget ) );
    l->addWidget( dlgPass );
    l->addWidget( new QDialogButtonBox( QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel, Qt::Horizontal, centralWidget ) );

    if( dlg.exec() != QDialog::Rejected )
    {
        ;
    }
    delete centralWidget;
    // (-> will cause crash later) show(); //Show LoginDialog again
}
```

There are no errors, it just crashes unexpectedly and sometimes it exits with code (0).

When analyzing with the debugger and really going through every single step it doesn't crash. The `LoginDialog` will be shown and it's not going to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the purpose of your `centralWidget` in the dialog? I don't think it is needed at all, and you can assemble your widgets directly in the dialog. I would rewrite your code in this way:

```
void LoginDialog::createAccount()
{
    QDialog dlg;
    dlg.setGeometry( this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height() );

    QLineEdit *dlgUser = new QLineEdit( &dlg );
    QLineEdit *dlgPass = new QLineEdit( &dlg );
    dlgPass->setEchoMode( QLineEdit::Password );

    QVBoxLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout;
    l->addWidget( new QLabel( tr("Username :"), &dlg ) );
    l->addWidget( dlgUser );
    l->addWidget( new QLabel( tr("Password :"), &dlg ) );
    l->addWidget( dlgPass );
    l->addWidget( new QDialogButtonBox( QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel, Qt::Horizontal, &dlg ) );

    dlg.setLayout( l );

    if( dlg.exec() != QDialog::Rejected )
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Davlog, ah, you hide the parent dialog while you open another modal child dialog that creates an account? Well, what if you just call `dlg.show()` instead of calling `dlg.exec()`?

Comment: hmm... I replaced the if statement with dlg.show() but it still crashes.

Comment: @Davlog, is the back trace for crash available?

Comment: QLabel and QDialogButtonBox do not need parent, since they are placed in a layout, which will reparent them

Comment: @vahancho I tried to check with the debugger where it crashes but everytime I go through it with the debugger it works... no crash, no bug :/

Comment: @Davlog, what if you hide the LoginDialog **after** showing the secondary dialog?